# Flutter - How to get Map data of an Array inside Firestore as Dropdownlist

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, drop-down-menu

I'm new in Flutter with Firebase. I'm trying to get all the name from array in Firestore as Dropdownlist.But I can't be able to get all the data in Dropdownlist. Can someone help me out to solve this problem? Thanks.

Firebase collection Image:

[image: Firebase collection Image]

**The whole sample data;**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DropDown extends StatefulWidget {

@override
_DropDownState createState() => _DropDownState();
}

class _DropDownState extends State<DropDown> {
 var Storagelocation;
 var setDefault = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();
   }


  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {

 return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title:Center(child: Text('Locations'))),
                body: Container(
                                        height: 185,
                                        child: Column(children: [
                                          Text('Main Location'),
                                        StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                                        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                            .collection('location')
                                            .snapshots(),
                                        builder: (BuildContext context,
                                            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                                          if (!snapshot.hasData) return Container();
                                          if (setDefault) {
                                            Storagelocation = snapshot.data.docs[0]['Location'][0]['name'];
                                            debugPrint('setDefault: $Storagelocation');
                                          }

                                          return DropdownButton(
                                            isExpanded: false,
                                            value: Storagelocation,
                                            items: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {

                                              return document['Location'].map((e){
                                                return DropdownMenuItem(
                                                  value: e['name'],
                                                  child: Text(e['name']),
                                                );
                                              });

                                            }).expand((element) => element).toList(),
                                              onChanged: (data) {
                                              setState(
                                                    () {
                                                  Storagelocation =data;
                                                },
                                              );
                                            },
                                          );
                                        },
                                      ),

                                      ]),
   ),
                              );

   }
   }
```

All I'm getting is **type 'List dynamic ' is not a subtype of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem dynamic ?'** at the place of Dropdownmenu.

Answer (score 0):

Try updated answer

```dart
 snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {

 return document['Location'].map((e){
    return DropdownMenuItem(
      value: e['name'],
      child: Text(e['name']),
      );
  });
  
  }).expand((element) => element).toList()
```

Comment out after try..!

Comment: I've tried and it doesn't work for me. it shows the error of  **type 'List dynamic ' is not a subtype of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>?'** . Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Try the new updated answer. If it works accept and vote the answer.

Comment: I've tried the new updated answer but it still doesn't work.

Comment: `type 'List dynamic ' is not a subtype of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>?'` Same error ?

Comment: Yes. Same error.

Comment: Share the sample data of the `snapshot.data.docs` contains. Just print the `snapshot.data.docs` and share the data.

Comment: Sorry,I didn't get it. You mean to share the whole data of the snapshot.data.docs contains?

Comment: Yes.The form of actual data  you are trying to use. That helps me lot.